# unable to resolve module create-react-class

Tags: react-native, native-base

I am new to react native.

After implementing native-base in my project, I am getting this error:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
 import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
 import {Header,Left,Right,Icon} from 'native-base'

    export default class DiningAreas extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
      super(props);
        this.state = {
        };
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Header>
          <Left Icon = 'menu'/>
        </Header>
        <Text> DiningAreas </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: did you tried what they mentioned in the error?

Comment: Yes, I have tried but unfortunately getting same issue

Comment: Are you using the latest version of native-base?

Comment: @Johan I am using latest version

Comment: watch-del-all && rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-* && rm -rf node_modules/ && npm cache verify && npm install && npm start -- --reset-cache should fix the problem, this is happening randomly, so cant reproduce this. last option would be installing create-react-class in node_modules